# Как растянуть страницу на весь экран?

Tags: css3, html

Здравствуйте! У меня есть сайт.

И у меня проблема: не знаю, как растянуть страницу до конца экрана. Рамка страницы как бы обтекает текст и заканчивается, где заканчивается текст. А я хочу, чтобы футер был в самом низу и, где нет текста, пусть будет пустое пространство.

Это мой style.css. Ниже есть и другие строки, но они относятся к описанию свойств, стилей кнопок, списков и др. мелочей.

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.bg-glad {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("images/page_gl.png");
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
#wrapper (основной контейнер в котором находится все за исключение футера) {
    background-color: #c9f8f8;
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0px auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 992px;
}
/* Header;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header {
    height: 175px;
}
.header-img {
    background-image: url("images/header.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    height: 175px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 992px;
}
#zag {
    color: #f6fe1c;
    font-family: Palatino Linotype, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 60px 0px 0px 15px;
    position: absolute;
}
#zag a {
    color: #f6fe1c;
    font-family: Palatino Linotype, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#zag a:hover {
    color: #fcffbd;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
/* begin Flash */
#art-flash-area {
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 175px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 992px;
}
#art-flash-container {
    height: 248px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -36px;
    width: 992px;
}
#art-flash-container div.art-flash-alt {
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 36px;
    width: 110px;
}
/* Header END;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Middle;
#middle (контейнер идущий сразу за хедером внутри wraper после хедера занимает все оставшееся пространство) {
    height: 1%;
    padding: 0 0 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
;
#middle:after {
    clear: both;
    content: '.';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
;
#container (находится в нутри middle соседствует с left sidbar) {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}
;
#content (контейнер внутри container содержащий контент) {
    background-color: #b1f6b9;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 5px -5px 225px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
}
;
/* menu (синее меню под хедером);
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.menu {
    background: url("images/nav.png") repeat-x;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 992px;
    z-index: 5;
}
.menu ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.menu ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    font: 16px "Palatino Linotype" Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover {
    background: url("images/nav_hover.png") repeat-x;
    display: block;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font: 16px "Palatino Linotype" Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
    z-index: 5;
}
/* Vipadayuchie menu;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#biz_menu {
    background: #0204a2;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 105px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#biz_menu div {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 10px;
}
#biz_menu div:hover {
    background: #3983f9;
}
#biz_menu a {
    color: #fff;
    font: 16px "Palatino Linotype";
    text-decoration: none;
}
#biz_menu a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    font: 16px "Palatino Linotype";
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#plati_menu {
    background: #0204a2;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 310px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#plati_menu div {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 30px 2px 10px;
}
#plati_menu div:hover {
    background: #3983f9;
}
#plati_menu a {
    color: #fff;
    font: 16px "Palatino Linotype";
    text-decoration: none;
}
#plati_menu a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    font: 16px "Palatino Linotype";
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#bg {
    background-image: url("images/vmenu1.png");
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#bg:hover {
    background-image: url("images/vmenu.png");
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#privat_menu {
    background: #0204a2;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 450px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#privat_menu span div {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 10px;
}
#privat_menu span div:hover {
    background: #3983f9;
}
#privat_menu a {
    color: #fff;
    font: 16px "Palatino Linotype";
    text-decoration: none;
}
#privat_menu a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    font: 16px "Palatino Linotype";
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#poker_menu {
    background: #0204a2;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 282px;
    margin-top: 130px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#poker_menu span div {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 10px;
}
#poker_menu span div:hover {
    background: #3983f9;
}
#poker_menu a {
    color: #fff;
    font: 16px "Palatino Linotype";
    text-decoration: none;
}
#poker_menu a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    font: 16px "Palatino Linotype";
    text-decoration: underline;
}
/* Sidebar Left (левый сайд бар находится в нутри middle);
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#sideLeft {
    background: #b1f6b9;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -220px;
    position: relative;
    top: 44px;
    width: 215px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#calend {
    display: block;
    margin: 15px;
}
.zagolovok {
    background-image: url("images/vmenu_sb.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
    font: Georgia, Geneva, sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Footer;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#footer {
    background: #b1f6b9;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: -50px auto 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 992px;
}
```

Comment: @Krezvaa, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 4):

```
html {
    height: 100%; //позволит растянуть сайт на 100% высоты
}
body {
    height: 100%; //позволит растянуть сайт на 100% высоты
}
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%; //выставляем минимальную высоту в 100%
    height: auto; // позволяем сайту тянуться если он больше по высоте
    margin: -50px auto 0; // поднимаем сайт вверх на высоту футера, тем самым освободив место под футер
}
#header {
    padding-top: 50px; //опустим содержимое хедера на высоту футера - вернув сайт на свое место 
}
#footer {
    height: 50px; //задаем высоту футера
    margin: 0 auto; //убираем подтягивание вверх которое сейчас присутствует
}
```

Таким способом мы "прилепим" футер к низу экрана если текста мало на сайте и опустим футер - если текста много и сайт больше по высоте чем экран. Мы избегаем позиционирования  при котором контент сайта залазит под футер. Работает при фиксированной высоте футера. Так же для старых браузеров нужны несколько дополнительных правил (старый ФФ и ИЕ).

Answer (score 0):

```
.bg-glad {height: 100%;}
```