# Уменьшить окно по размеру экрана на странице сайта.

Tags: css3, html

Доброго времени суток. Мне подсказали как растянуть страницу до конца экрана (прижать футер к низу)
 [Как растянуть страницу на весь экран?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/139222/html-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD)

Я используя данные советы добился резултата, но возникла еще одна не большая неприятность.
Но так как жизнь состоит из мелочей, эта мелочь меня немного раздражает и поэтому хотелось бы ее устранить.

Суть в следующем:

http://krezland.ru/

http://krezland.ru/index.php?page=plati/start.html

На этих двух страницах не достаточно контента для заполнения целого экрана. Но проблема заключается в том, что по какой-то причине страница прилепляет футер не до конца экрана, а еще на пол экрана в низ и из-за этого появляется с правой стороны полоса прокрутки когда она совсем не нужна.

Как избавиться от этого недостатка и зделать так, чтобы на таких страницах футер прилеплялся точно к низу экрана, без полосы прокрутки пустого пространства?

Comment: Здесь HTML не поддерживается. Приведите запрос к нормальному виду.

Comment: У Вас ошибчка `</br>` замените на `<br />`. Но это не касается решению проблемы

Comment: А когда пишешь сообщение с права написано что поддерживается.

Answer (score 1):

Вы невнимательно прочитали то, что я ответил вам в прошлом вопросе. Не все перенесли в стили, а кое-что перенесли неправильно. Результат закономерный.

```
.bg-glad {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper{
  height: auto !important;
  margin: -50px auto 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #C9F8F8;
}
#header {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.header-img {
  top: 50px;
}
```

Показал основные стили которых нет или имеют неправильные значения.

P.S. Эти стили надо добавить к существующим.